# Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, backup

I am trying to execute `backUp` and `restore` command in my application that it modeled by `EF6`.

For my backup I create a `Sp` as you can see here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetBackUp
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @address nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    BACKUP DATABASE [db-invoice-169] to DISK=@address
END
GO
```

In my application I call this `Sp`

```
 private void Backup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            string str_filename = string.Empty;
            sfd.FileName = "backup_database_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "_");
            sfd.Filter = @"backup files(*.bak)|*.bak|all files(*.*)|*.*";
            sfd.FilterIndex = 1;
            sfd.OverwritePrompt = true;
            sfd.Title = "***save backup files***";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                str_filename = sfd.FileName;
                backup(str_filename);
            }
        }
        private void backup(string str_filename)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"EXEC [dbo].[back_up] @address = N'"+str_filename+"'");
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                MessageBox.Show("عملیات پشتیبان گیری موفقیت آمیز بود");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("عملیات پشتیبان گیری موفقیت آمیز نبود |" + ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

But I got this error:

> Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction.  BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"EXEC [dbo].[back_up] @address = N'"+str_filename+"'");
```

to:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, @"EXEC [dbo].[back_up] @address = N'"+str_filename+"'");
```

Abrar

Answer (score 0):

Try this before backup code

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
{
    // Add you backup query or your stuff
    ts.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According abrar answer I have this error with restore process in SQLlocaldb and Entity Framework:

```
RESTORE cannot process database 'database' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation.
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

The solution:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, @"USE master EXEC [dbo].[back_up] @address = N'"+str_filename+"'")
```

Comment: You almost literally repeat another answer.That's not helpful, it only adds noise. Apart from that, what is `[dbo].[back_up]`? Can you show the source code? I highly doubt that you happen to have the same stored procedure as in the question.

Comment: In my case abrar's solution not work, because I use EntityFramework and SQLLocalBD, for this reason I consider change abrar's solution, including "USE master " if someone has the same problem, and I wrote:  "According abrar's answer I have this error with restore process in SQLlocaldb and Entity Framework" and "[dbo].[back_up]" is the SP backup name. What is the confusion?